# How to delete firebase firestore collection document if you don't know the document name?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating "save item to favorites" function so that when user clicks the heart icon, the item gets added to his collection. However I am struggling to add the "unlike" function, so when the user clicks the heart button again, I want to delete that item from his collection.

Unfortunately I don't have the access to that selected items document ID, but I know the field that makes the item unique inside that document.

Here is some pseudo code of what I am trying to do:

```
  const favoriteButtonUnlikeHandler = () => {
    db.collection("users")
    .doc(`${auth.currentUser?.uid}`)
    .collection("meals")
    // where document.ingredient_uid === recipePreview.ingredient_uid
    .delete()
  }
```

**recipePreview** is the selected item that I want to delete and **recipePreview.ingredient_uid** is the identifier of that item.

How can I filter through the collection and find document id that matches my selected item?

[image]

**edit:**
This is how I am currently accessing the data:

```
  const [favoriteMeals, setFavoriteMeals] = useContext(favoriteMealsContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(`${auth.currentUser?.uid}`)
      .collection("meals")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        setFavoriteMeals(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
      });
  }, []);

return (
<>
{favoriteMeals.map((meal) => (
              <MealResult/>
))}
</>
)
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement.?please paste at least the screen shot of the sample db

Comment: @pepe sry just added, basically I want to loop through meals collection and delete the document that has document with highlighted ingredient_uid value.

Comment: If you want to delete a document you should have the document id of that document.You will definitely get document id while you reading the document.By the way how you are accessing the data.?

Comment: What is keeping you from doing `.where("ingredient_iod", "==", recipePreview.ingredient_uid)`? See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#web_1

Answer (score 0):

If you have any information about the document, like the Ingredient uid you can create a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators) with the info you have to find it. Something like this, as suggested in the comments:

```js
    var delete_query = db.collection("users").doc(`${auth.currentUser?.uid}`).collection("meals").where("incredient_uid", ==, recipePreview.ingredient_uid);
    delete_query.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
            doc.ref.delete();
        });
    });
```

Take into account that you need to use the doc.[ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#ref) instead of using directly de .delete()